# Symfony DIC - Reinitialize instance

Tags: php, symfony

I am using Symfony DIC using yaml file for example

```
services:
    mailer:
        class:     Mailer
        arguments: ['%mailer.transport%']
    newsletter_manager:
        class:     NewsletterManager
        calls:
            - [setMailer, ['@mailer']]
```

And then i am fetching the object by using

```
->getContainer()
->get('newsletter_manager');
```

How can i create a new instance of the object each time i am getting it? I want to reinitialize it for every use.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [symfony docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/shared.html):

> In order to always get a new instance, set the shared setting to false in your service definition:
>
> ```
> services:
>     AppBundle\SomeNonSharedService:
>         shared: false
> ```